# Liquibase script to make all data in a column uppercase

Tags: sql, database, liquibase

I have a problem where the data in a particular column is stored as lowercase (This problem occurs only in MSSQL).I had thought of writing a change set to force uppercase in that particular column, but I am not sure on how to go about it

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Try the following changeset:

```xml
<changeSet author="mark" id="2013-07-15-01">
    <update tableName="MyTable">
        <column name="MyColumn" valueComputed="upper(MyColumn)"/>
    </update>
</changeSet>
```

Documented [here](http://www.liquibase.org/documentation/changes/update.html).

Comment: Do you know what happens with the `valueComputed` if I use an ORM like this?
`datasource: driver-class-name: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver` `jpa: show-sql: false properties: hibernate: dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect`
If I use `valueComputed="myfunction(...)"`, is `myfunction(...)` interpreted at Liquibase / ORM level or is it passed as it is to the MySQL database? I'm asking this because I don't know if the dialect knows about all supported MySQL functions.

Comment: @ROMANIA_engineer Should work. The documentation states it's just a function call: https://www.liquibase.org/documentation/column.html

Answer (score -4):

try this :

```
 UPDATE
  MyTable
SET
  MyColumn = upper(MyColumn)
```

Comment: Hi, That is a SQL query. How would i implement it in a liquibase changeset?